# texmaker, labeled equations, tables, figures,

Tags: texmaker

I am working with a rather long tex file in texmaker.
Actually, it is not a single file, but I am combining different tex files together and making a single pdf (using \include{}).

Is there a way to see all the labeled equations, figures, tables in a small window while working on the file?
you now, like the usual "view list of open files" that exists in texmaker.

Answer (score 3):

The "Structure" panel on the left has a "LABELS" entry that you can expand to see all the labeled items in each file. It is also shown in the screenshot in the the Texmaker website.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: great thanks! it really makes everything simpler.